# Convert Xml config to resource.groovy

Tags: grails, groovy

I am new to grails and i want to convert xml configuration to resource.groovy. but there are namespaces in xml. i don't want to duplicate config here.there should be one configuration which would be resource.groovy

my xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xmlns:neo4j="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/neo4j"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-2.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/neo4j
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/neo4j/spring-neo4j.xsd">

            <context:component-scan base-package="neo4j"></context:component-scan>


    <util:map id="config">
        <entry key="ha.server_id" value="2" />
        <entry key="ha.initial_hosts" value="127.0.0.1:5001,127.0.0.1:5002" />
        <!-- put in more config parameters here, http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/ha-configuration.html -->
    </util:map>
    <bean id="graphDbFactory"
        class="org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.HighlyAvailableGraphDatabaseFactory" />
    <bean id="graphDbBuilder" factory-bean="graphDbFactory"
        factory-method="newHighlyAvailableDatabaseBuilder">
        <constructor-arg value="/home/alok/Desktop/data4" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="graphDbBuilderFinal" factory-bean="graphDbBuilder"
        factory-method="setConfig">
        <constructor-arg ref="config" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="graphDatabaseService" factory-bean="graphDbBuilderFinal"
        factory-method="newGraphDatabase" destroy-method="shutdown" />

    <neo4j:config graphDatabaseService="graphDatabaseService"   base-package="neo4j"/>
    <neo4j:repositories base-package="neo4j" />

</beans>
```

I want to know how there i have to handle namespaces and constructor-arguments

Comment: you are aware, that you can just copy it as resource.xml right beside the resource.groovy?

Comment: yes ,i have to do  configuration using resource.groovy using groovy pattern

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You really have two questions here, but let's answer both of them.

How do you use name spaces in `resources.groovy`?

Here is how:

```
// resources.groovy
beans {
  xmlns neo4j:"http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/neo4j"
  xmlns context:"http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
  ... // and so on.
  // neo4j.repositories
}
```

How do you use constructor-arguments in `resources.groovy`?

Here is how:

```
// resources.groovy
beans {
  someBean(
    SomeBeanClass, 
    'stringArg1', 
    ['listOfStringsArg2', 'listOfStringArg2-a'],
    ref('someOtherBeanAsArg3')
  )
}
```

Comment: thanks,but there is problem to handle schema location which have multiple urls.

Comment: Multiple URLs? How so? All of the ones you listed there have only one.

Comment: ok, how to handle schema location.

xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-2.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/neo4j
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/neo4j/spring-neo4j.xsd">

Comment: I will update the answer to show you that you can add more than one, and you don't need to define the schemaLocation when using the bean builder DSL.

Comment: sorry one more stupid question here,in xml, we pass factory-method to some arguments and it returns object. so in resource.groovy,how it will be ?